# setstate not updating ui flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, setstate

in debug I see that the data is saved, but the UI is not updated with the data. strange thing is that if I press CMD S to update the simulator, the data pops out… so the data saves it for me. but i can't understand why i don't update the UI

```
    class _GiornoSettimanaleState extends State<GiornoSettimanale> {
  List<AperturaWrapper> aperture = [];
  bool _isClosed = false;

  Future _selectTimeApertura(BuildContext context, {int i = 0}) async {
    final TimeOfDay? _pickedTime =
        await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now());
    if (_pickedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget.orari[i].apertura = '${_pickedTime.hour}:${_pickedTime.minute}';
        if (i > 0) aperture[i - 1].orario.apertura = widget.orari[i].apertura;
      });
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            AutoSizeText(
              widget.giornoSettimanale!.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: Fonts.bold,
                color: AppColors().black,
              ),
            ),
            Checkbox(
              value: _isClosed,
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isClosed = value;
                    aperture.forEach((element) => element.isClosed = value);
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
            AutoSizeText('SHOPS_CLOSE_ALL'.tr),
          ],
        ),
        AperturaWidget(
          onTapApertura: _isClosed ? null : () => _selectTimeApertura(context),
          onTapChiusura: _isClosed ? null : () => _selectTimeChiusura(context),
          valoreApertura: widget.orari[0].apertura,
          valoreChiusura: widget.orari[0].chiusura,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: aperture.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => aperture[i],
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const SizedBox(height: 5);
            },
          ),
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final Orario nuovoOrario = Orario();
            widget.orari.add(nuovoOrario);
            final lastIndex = widget.orari.length - 1;
            final apertura = AperturaWrapper(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              onTapApertura: () => _selectTimeApertura(context, i: lastIndex),
              onTapChiusura: () => _selectTimeChiusura(context, i: lastIndex),
              orario: widget.orari[lastIndex],
            );
            apertura.onRemove = () => _removeApertura(nuovoOrario, apertura);
            setState(() {
              aperture.add(apertura);
            });
          },
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Icon(Icons.add),
              SizedBox(
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  'SHOP_ADD'.tr,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

UPDATE the code with the widget build where i call ListView generate

```
    class AperturaWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  AperturaWrapper({
    required this.onTapApertura,
    required this.onTapChiusura,
    required this.orario,
    Key? key,
    this.onRemove,
    this.isClosed = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  VoidCallback? onRemove;
  VoidCallback onTapApertura;
  VoidCallback onTapChiusura;
  Orario orario
  bool? isClosed;

  @override
  _AperturaWrapperState createState() => _AperturaWrapperState();
}

class _AperturaWrapperState extends State<AperturaWrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: AperturaWidget(
            onTapApertura: widget.onTapApertura,
            onTapChiusura: widget.onTapChiusura,
            valoreApertura: widget.orario.apertura,
            valoreChiusura: widget.orario.chiusura,
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: widget.onRemove,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE WITH AperturaWidget class, class that is used by my list, which does not update the ui

the first portion, that is [0], the ui is always updated, while the rest is not, although in debug I see that the data is saved.the ui is not updated only for the new part of the list that I create, while for [0] it is updated immediately

Comment: Where do you use this `Padding` widget, could you share that part of your code as well?

Comment: @PeterKoltai update

Comment: One thing is sure, setting `widget.orario` in `setState` will not update anything, but I am not sure it is your problem. Your problem is 'Padding` widget is not updating? What is `AperturaWrapper`, can you add class definition?

Comment: @PeterKoltai the problem is that the ui of the list in question is not updated, but only [0], in debug the data however saves it. and if I do CMD S to update the simulator the data appears ..

Comment: Every variable that a stateful widget is dependent on should be declared as a (private) member in the corresponding `State<>` class. You have to use this values in the `build` method of the `State<>` class, and rebuild occurs when you call `setState`. Setting `widget.` variables will not trigger a rebuild.

Comment: @PeterKoltai ah ok .. do you think this is the problem? which variable in detail should I modify?

Comment: I don't know, I looked at the code but couldn't try it, it is only an idea, for example `setState(() { widget.orari[i].apertura` seems unusual to me, and I think it is not tracked by Flutter Engine when rebuilding a stateful widget (it is in another class).

Comment: @PeterKoltai what could i use?

Comment: I think but not sure that if changes of `widget.orari[i].apertura` must be reflected in the UI, this should be a member in the `State<>` class.

Comment: @PeterKoltai where exactly do I put it? sorry but I'm a beginner with flutter

Comment: like as you do with `_isClosed` in `_GiornoSettimanaleState`, to `_AperturaWrapperState` I guess, but I can't really help you in details, I can't run your code and it is quite complicated. I would suggest to dive deeper into state management with Flutter.